# Delphi Prism, how to declare a constant bounded array of enum

Tags: delphi-xe, delphi-prism

I get a compilation error

[Error  1   (PE114) Type "array[0..1] of ConsoleApplication.MyEnum" used from type "ConsoleApplication." must be public D:\PrismProjects\ConsoleApplication\ConsoleApplication\Program.pas  14  42  ConsoleApplication]

when I try to compile the following code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication;

interface

type
  ConsoleApp = class
    public
      class method Main(args: array of string);
  end;

  MyEnum = (F, T);

const
  EnumOfBool: array[boolean] of MyEnum = [MyEnum.F, MyEnum.T];

implementation

  class method ConsoleApp.Main(args: array of string);
  begin
    Console.WriteLine('Hello World.');
  end;
end.
```

Comment: The code which you post does not generate this error, try posting the real code. Also your declaration of the `EnumOfBool` array is correct ,but try to avoid of using global members even if Delphi Prism allow this.

Answer (score 0):

Where is MyEnum defined? I'm pretty sure wherever that is, it is not marked as public (as the error message suggests), but it's left on the default visibility (which is private in .NET).

Then RRUZ is correct in his comment, you should avoid global declarations. The Oxygene compiler needs to create a (invisible, auto-generated) class containing this as a static (class) member anyways because .NET does not allow for global declarations, so you should do it 'right' in the first place.